# Zoom effect in a UIView image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uiviewanimation

[image: Below is the image of human body]

When user hovers over the image,tapping on certain body part presents the magnified image of that area. I wanted to know any possible third party frameworks that address such kind of feature or code snippets(like using which gesturerecognizers) that can help me attain this feature.

Question 2: Also I have to add a dynamic clickable Label at the point where the touch happens and ends (as you can see the wrist label in image) so that I can take the user to a separate view from this screen on clicking the label. How to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your drawRect method, mask off a circle (using a monochrome bitmap containing the 'mask' of your magnifying glass) and draw your subject view in there with a 2x scale transform. Then draw a magnifying glass image over that and you're done.

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect {
    CGContextRef    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect          bounds = self.bounds;
    CGImageRef      mask = [UIImage imageNamed: @"loupeMask"].CGImage;
    UIImage         *glass = [UIImage imageNamed: @"loupeImage"];

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, bounds, mask);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bounds);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 2.0, 2.0);

    //draw your subject view here

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    [glass drawInRect: bounds];
}
```

Check [this](http://www.craftymind.com/2009/02/10/creating-the-loupe-or-magnifying-glass-effect-on-the-iphone/) link for complete example.

Comment: hey, do u have any thoughts on the second question i added?

Comment: Hey, once you will manage to draw the circle then add the dynamic label in front of the circle. (using label with tag will be banificial  while deleting it.)